# How to split code when using inversify js?

Tags: inversion-of-control, inversifyjs

```
@injectable()
class Ninja implements Warrior {
    @inject(TYPES.Weapon) private _katana: Weapon;
    @inject(TYPES.ThrowableWeapon) private _shuriken: ThrowableWeapon;
    public fight() { return this._katana.hit(); }
    public sneak() { return this._shuriken.throw(); }
}
```

```js
// file inversify.config.ts

import { Container } from "inversify";
import { TYPES } from "./types";
import { Warrior, Weapon, ThrowableWeapon } from "./interfaces";
import { Ninja, Katana, Shuriken } from "./entities";

const myContainer = new Container();
myContainer.bind<Warrior>(TYPES.Warrior).to(Ninja);
myContainer.bind<Weapon>(TYPES.Weapon).to(Katana);
myContainer.bind<ThrowableWeapon>(TYPES.ThrowableWeapon).to(Shuriken);

export { myContainer };
```

Take this code for example, how could one import `Shuriken` dynamically in order to code split?

I've been looking into `hierarchical DI systems`,  `provider injection`, and `Asynchronous container modules` but none of it seems appropriate.

`Shuriken` could have other dependencies from di as well. so  `provider injection` doesn't fit the bill.

`hierarchical DI systems` feels like that for every class that is intended to be loaded dynamically, a child container must be created.

How to split code in inversify?

Comment: by split code, do you mean for tree-shaking?

Comment: more like lazy load(await import) some modules in order to not immediately download files not critical for rendering @thelastshadow

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but I think you can do:

```js
let container = new Container();

// toDynamicValue isn't executed until the TYPES.ThrowableWeapon is requested
container.<ThrowableWeapon>(TYPES.ThrowableWeapon).toDynamicValue((context) => { 
  return new Promise((resolve){
    // where 'dependency' is a module that defines and returns an AsyncContainerModule
    // that file will need to load the dependencies for the AsyncContainerModule
    // but won't be loaded until this require is called.
    require('dependency').then((dep) => {
      await container.loadAsync(dep);
      resolve(container.get('Shuriken'));
    });
  });
});
```